# How to write a matrix in a different basis by using Mathematica

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I have these two 4x4 matrix

```
Subscript[S, 1] = KroneckerProduct[PauliMatrix[1], IdentityMatrix[2]]
Subscript[S, 2] = KroneckerProduct[IdentityMatrix[2], PauliMatrix[2]]
```

Which are written in the Canonical basis `({{{1}, {0}, {0}, {0}};{{{0}, {1}, {0}, {0}}; {{{0}, {0}, {1}, {0}}; {{{0}, {0}, {0}, {1}})`

I would like to write down these two matrices in the following basis:

```
G := {{0}, {0}, {0}, {1}}

S := (1/Sqrt[2]) {{0}, {1}, {1}, {0}}

A := (1/Sqrt[2]) {{0}, {1}, {-1}, {0}}

EE := {{1}, {0}, {0}, {0}}
```

Is there any way to do it in Mathematica?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Crossposted [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2324604).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be

```
Subscript[S, 1] = KroneckerProduct[PauliMatrix[1], IdentityMatrix[2]]
Subscript[S, 2] = KroneckerProduct[IdentityMatrix[2], PauliMatrix[2]]
basis = {{0, 0, 0, 1}, (1/Sqrt[2]) {0, 1, 1, 0}, (1/Sqrt[2]) {0, 1, -1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0}};
Inverse[basis].Subscript[S, 1].Transpose[basis]
Inverse[basis].Subscript[S, 2].Transpose[basis]
```

> {{0, 1/Sqrt[2], 1/Sqrt[2], 0}, {1/Sqrt[2], 0, 0, 1/Sqrt[2]}, {1/Sqrt[
> 2], 0, 0, -(1/Sqrt[2])}, {0, 1/Sqrt[2], -(1/Sqrt[2]), 0}}
>
> {{0, I/Sqrt[2], -(I/Sqrt[2]), 0}, {-(I/Sqrt[2]), 0, 0, I/Sqrt[2]}, {I/
> Sqrt[2], 0, 0, I/Sqrt[2]}, {0, -(I/Sqrt[2]), -(I/Sqrt[2]), 0}}

Comment: I understood what you have done but when I reply it I do not get a matrix as the result. Instead, I get only the full expression of the products.

Comment: Of course, you have to define `Subscript[S, 1] ` and `Subscript[S, 2]`, first.